# Listing the channels in IRC

Tags: irc

**Background information**
My IRC client is Weechat.

**Questions**

1. While trying to list the users i am getting a huge list of channels on freenode. Is there any way i can control the list to see it page by page in the weechat client using commands?
2. I have tried the command /list -min 5 and -max 20 to list the channels based on the number of users. This is also not working.

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

WeeChat has a script available for more convenient /list interface (`/script install listbuffer.py`), however, it is somewhat incompatible with the current versions and might end up crashing while retrieving the list.

The options `-min` and `-max` are not actually for `/list`, but for the `/msg alis list` command which calls the ALIS channel search service (which was a freenode-specific feature).

But note that the 'freenode' network that exists now is **not the same** as the 'freenode' network that existed for two decades until last month. The current 'freenode' is under a different management and has almost nothing in common with the old one (except for the domain name), while the majority of communities have moved to various other networks (OFTC, Libera.Chat, etc.)

In particular, the new network uses different server software and does not have ALIS available, although it happens to have similar filtering extensions to the /list command as the old one did.

I'm not sure if I have the new syntax correct, but:

|  | Old freenode | New freenode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server software | Charybdis/ircd-seven + Atheme | InspIRCd + Anope2 |
| List all channels | `/list` | `/list` |
| List channels by user count | `/list >5,<20` | `/list >5 <20` |
| List by user count #2 | `/msg alis list * -min 5 -max 20` (Note that ALIS only shows 60 results max.) | — (ALIS is not available.) |
| Search channels by name | `/msg alis list gentoo` | `/list *gentoo*` |
| List by name & size | `/msg alis list xyz -min 5 -max 20` | `/list *xyz* >5 <20` |
| Is it a good network? | yes | no |